# Healthchecks fail when using ALB routing via hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs

I have two services using two ALBs. In order to cut costs, I would like to use the same ALB to fan out to different target groups where my applications are registered. The problem is that once I configure the routing and attach the target group to the rule, my applications cannot register in the target group since they start failing the healthchecks. Am I missing something here?

Comment: With extra details of your setup, its impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks! I actually answered my own question, I forgot to open the port in the ECS service group :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the new port in the ECS service group *facepalm*.